# Why is this implicit instance not seen by the Scala compiler

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats

I've defined the following method:

```
def add(
  prefix: List[String],
  resourceName: String,
  subTree: ResourceTree): ResourceTree = {
  //import ResourceTreeInstances.semigroupInstance
  implicit val dummyInstance = ResourceTreeInstances.semigroupInstance

  // Make a resource tree with a single path.
  def mkSinglePathRT(gPrefix: List[String]): ResourceTree = ???


  this |+| mkSinglePathRT(prefix)
}
```

As you can see, I need to use the |+| method of `Semigroup`, defined in the Cats library. I've [defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39621963/defining-a-semigroup-instance-that-depends-on-itself) an instance of `Semigroup` for `ResourceTree`, however, importing it using the commented import does not work (the `|+|` operator is not found). Having the `dummyInstance` above solves the problem, however this does not looks right.

Any idea about why the instance is not brought up by this import?

Comment: Is `ResourceTreeInstances.semigroupInstance` defined as an implicit? If not, that's your issue.

Comment: it is. It's definition is given in the linked question. You pointed out there that  I missed the result type at the instance. Could that be the problem?

Comment: As a side note, assuming that you have a Cats dependency in the project where `ResourceTree` is defined, putting the semigroup instance in the `ResourceTree` companion object would allow you to avoid the import altogether. What you have now is the equivalent of an orphan instance in Haskell—putting the instance in the companion object is like defining it in the same module as the data type in Haskell.

Comment: I have the instances in the same file as `ResourceTree` under an object named `ResourceTreeInstances`. Does this also make the instances of `ResourceTree` orphan?

Comment: Yep. It has to be in the companion object.

Comment: By the way I can't reproduce your issue with the combined code from the two questions, so it might be a good idea to post a complete example (with all imports).

Comment: It seems the problem was the lack of a type in the instance. Try removing it. You should see the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123878/discussion-between-damian-nadales-and-travis-brown).